# How to create a mongoose sub model without creating a collection for it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const walletTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        a: {type: Boolean, required: true},   
    },
    {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}});

const walletSchema = new Schema({
    b: {type: Boolean, required: true},       
    transactions: [{type: walletTransactionSchema}],
});

walletSchema.index({'transactions': 1}, {sparse: true});   


module.exports.Wallet = mongoose.model('Wallet', walletSchema, 'wallets');
module.exports.WalletTransaction = mongoose.model('WalletTransaction', walletTransactionSchema);
```

I'm trying to create a model for a subdocument (WalletTransaction) without creating a collection for it. Unfortunately mongoose is automatically creating that collection. How can I prevent that behavior and just define a sub-model without creating a collection. I prefer to organize my schemas by refactoring them instead of just embedding them.
I used to do this without trouble with above definitions. I guess after updating to mongoose 6.0.8 (from 5.13) this is happend.

Answer (score 0):

For subdocuments you shouldn't need to actually create a model just the schema.  Then when you want to add a subdocument (transactions in your case you) would just pass an object that matches the schema.  That will prevent the subdocument collection from being created.

Here is a github issue about it - https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11498

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna create another model inside a model
You should go with the following approach

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true},
    about:{type:String},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    friends: [new mongoose.Schema({
        user: {type: String}
    }, {strict: false})],
    profileImage: {type: String, default: "default.jpg"},
    userName: {type: String, required: true},
    matches: {type: Number, default: 0},
    wins: {type: Number, default: 0},
    losses: {type: Number, default: 0},
    backgroundImage: {type: String, default: "default.jpg"},
    resetPasswordToken: {type: String, required: false},
    resetPasswordExpires: {type: Date, required: false},
    isDeleted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    deletedAt: {type: Date, default: null},
}, {timestamps: true}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Like this I create another model in my User model with name Friends in which each entry has **one** specific **id**

Comment: Too much codes. Just higlight the releveant part of the codes.